# Detaching from screen inside a byobu session

Tags: screen, byobu

For quite some time I've been using `screen` to detach and let them run in the background. Then I discovered `byobu` to have mutliple tabbed shells running. Now I have a problem that I'm no longer able to detach from a `screen` inside my `byobu` shells, since `Ctrl-a-d` detaches the byobu session and not the `screen` session inside it.

I read a few times that `Ctrl-a` is supposed to work, which would make this `Ctrl-a-a-d`, but this simply switches tabs (`Ctrl-a-a`) and then quits the shell (`Ctrl-d`).

Is there a simple solution to be able to detach again?

Answer (score 10):

Try letting go of ctrl after the first a, so the sequence is ctrl-a, a, d. Man screen:

```
   C-a C-a     (other)       Toggle  to  the  window  displayed previously.  Note that this
                             binding defaults to the command character typed twice,  unless
                             overridden.   For instance, if you use the option "-e]x", this
                             command becomes "]]".

   C-a a       (meta)        Send the command character (C-a) to window.  See  escape  com‐
                             mand.
```

Or if you're using tmux instead of screen for Byobu, try just ctrl-a d. Byobu's default prefix key is ctrl-b, so if you're using that default, doubling up the ctrl-a keystroke would not be necessary.

Comment: Sadly this did not work, I have my byobu backend configured to be tmux, I'll check out the tmux documentation to see whether that works.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that was possible. In that case, the extra ctrl-a may not be necessary; I have updated my answer to cover tmux.

Comment: Hm, that detached byobu as well. But as far as I can see there is no similar detach binding in tmux. I'll quickly switch to the screen backend.

Comment: This works for detaching screen inside of a tmux session when you have bound the tmux to C-a. I think these comments are googlable :)